# useEffect does not go to if statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Do not actually understand why this code part not working as it should.
This `useEffect` block re-renders on every scrollY position. Also, I see that this code part: `console.log(wrapperRef.current.style.opacity);` should call if and else if statements, but it does not.

Here is the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(wrapperRef.current.style.opacity);
    if (wrapperRef.current.style.opacity === 0) {
      setIsHidden(true);
      console.log("true");
    } else if (wrapperRef.current.style.opacity === 1) {
      setIsHidden(false);
      console.log("false");
    }
  }, [position]);
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also share the other block of 
code where setIsHidden called?

Comment: I just created another useEffect with ```isHidden``` dependency, which ```console.log``` current ```isHidden``` state. However, it is never being called

Comment: Also, it should ```console.log``` in the first block that I provided

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: String Values]

As you can see here, style values are strings, but with the [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) operator you also check for type equality.

This means you check that `'0' === 0` which are not the same types and also why your check never enters the if body.

Either check for `'0'` or use the `==` operator which does ignore types.

Comment: Oh God, yes, in the photo we can see that the numbers are strings (not blue color, which represents a type of number)